# Wordpress site got Error 500 after disactivating plugin

Tags: html, wordpress, plugins, cpanel, http-status-code-500

Site : https://www.orangefashionvillage.com/
Build on Wordpress with Divi theme

I'm freaking out right now because we were not able to make any changes to a webpage because of a plugin conflict. So I put the site in maintenance mode, did a backup with a plugin (but left the backup in the plugin and didn't download it... yeah my bad) and proceeded to disactivate the plugins one by one to determine the culprit.

The second I disactivated Really Simple SSL and OmniSend (for newsletters), the site received an error 500 and I cannot access the wp-amin either (error 500 there too).

- I tried to install a clean .htaccess, without avail.
- I tried to reinstall those 2 plugins using the cpanel, without avail.
- I tried disactivating all plugins by changing the plugin folder name, without
  avail.
- I tried updating PHP to latest version, without avail.
- I tried enabling WP_DEBUG but no errors are being generated.
- Entered define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M'); in the wp-config.php to see if it was a PHP memory limit issue

Answer (score 0):

1)put them in wp-config.php

```
 define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
 define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
```

2. Increasing Your PHP Memory Limit in WordPress by add

   define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M' );
3. try to use the default theme

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! Turns out it was rocket loader in our Cloudflare...